# How do I test if a private method has a field with a name and a type?

Tags: java, junit, junit5, java-11

Here is the private method I am trying to test:

```java
    private int privateMethod(int[] numbers) {
        var sum = 0;
        for (int number : numbers) {
            sum += number;
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

I am doing this in Java 11.

And following is my test using Junit 5:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.platform.commons.function.Try;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Optional;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;
import static org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.*;


   @Test
    public void assertPrivateMethodExistence() {
        final String methodName = "privateMethod";
        final Optional<Class<?>> maybeClass = getAppClass();
        Class<?> aClass = maybeClass.get();
        Optional<Method> maybeMethod = findMethod(aClass, methodName, int[].class);
        assertTrue(maybeMethod.isPresent(), methodName + " should be present in " + aClass.getCanonicalName());

        final Method method = maybeMethod.get();
        assertTrue(isPrivate(method), methodName + " should be private");

        assertEquals(int.class, method.getReturnType(), methodName + " should return type should be 'int'");
    }
```

I am making use of [ReflectionUtils](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.3/api/org/junit/platform/commons/util/ReflectionUtils.html) class

I wanted to know if there is a way to test that `privateMethod` contains a variable called `sum` and its type is `int`?

Comment: *I wanted to know if there is a way to test that privateMethod contains a variable called sum and its type is int?* No. Because it could be named `total` and typed `int` and generate the exact same byte code.

Comment: Why would you attempt to test that? Unit testing should test the *effect* of the method, which in this case mean to test if it calculates the correct return value. *How* is calculates the return value is internal to the method and not what you test, only the *result* should be tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Eliot Frisch mentioned in the comments, you cannot, since variable names aren't represented in the byte code.

Moreover, you really shouldn't. You could change the variable's name and have a method which **exactly** the same functionality:

```java
private int privateMethod(int[] numbers) {
    var notSum = 0;
    for (int number : numbers) {
        notSum += number;
    }
    return notSum;
}
```

so why would you want your unit test to break from such a refactoring?

Comment: You can preserve parameter names in your Byte code with compiler option  '-parameters'. If relying on that feature is a good idea remains to be discussed.

Comment: @johanneslink I don't believe it is. The unit test should test the functions functionality. I think Mureinik is on the right track. So, I propose changing it to: `return Arrays.stream(numbers).sum();` - now it has no local variables at all. I would also make it a `static` method. It does not depend on any class members.